# Effect of PWM mode of DC to DC convertor

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter

When using PWM from microcontroller to control DC-DC converter I prefer fast PWM which basically saw tooth wavwform compare to PWM value for fastest frequency. But we also have phase correct PWM which is symatic triangle waveform that compare to PWM value. If we set both signal with same frequency are there any advantage or which mode is preform better in which situation?

Comment: A sawtooth with frequency f and a triangle with frequency f produce the same PWM duty cycle for a given input voltage.

Comment: I meant PWM that gennerate from microcontroller for saw tooth, it count from zero to TOP then reset to zero but for triangle, it count up from zero to TOP then count down from TOP to zero and repeat. So I can generate higher frequency with fast PWM.

Comment: Then they don't have the same frequency; the triangle will be 0.5f and the saw will be f. How does that reshape your question?

Comment: Symmetric might result in a pulse train that is easier to filter, all other things being equal. I'm not going to attempt to prove it one way or t'uther, if nobody else feels like doing it, you can simulate it very quickly. Not directly related, but a sawtooth has a lot more power at lower harmonics than a triangle wave.

Comment: @Andyaka I assumed that I can divide the clock frequency to set both PWM signal to the same frequency

Comment: The sawtooth has both odd and even harmonics, while the triangle has only odd harmonics. This means the noise is higher for the sawtooth. OTOH, the triangle has two edges that can carry information, while the sawtooth has only one. This makes the sawtooth preferred in DC applications, where it's easier to deal with only one variable edge of the PWM, while the triangle is more suited to SPWM applications, due to the symmetry of the waveform.

Comment: The pulse centered mode (symmetric) is more useful when you are generating different signal (for example the phases of a motor) since they are not switching at the same time (so less transients and less noise). For an individual PWM I don't see an advantage

Comment: If the sawtooth/triangle wave is not at a high enough frequency compared to the wave you are comparing it to that the wave is more or less flat across the sawtooth, you'll get a more even response to rise and fall in the reference wave with the triangle wave than the sawtooth.